# Explination of Javascript function(return value&input parameter related)

Tags: javascript, input, return

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function pala(data) {
                    $("#pala").html(data.level);
                    }
                    $(document).ready(
                        function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/ragnaros/sanral?fields=talents&jsonp=pala",
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'jsonp'
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

In my eyes the function pala is closed on 4 line in the javascript but for some reason it continues(?).
Anyone that can simply how I read this sort of javascript cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: That function will populate #pala with what i'm assuming is the ajax response data. In what way does it "continue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pala is effectively just doing one thing (`$("#pala").html(data.level);`). The rest of the code runs because `$(document).ready(function)` executes the function when the body is loaded.

Here is your code with correct indentation (easier to understand).

```
function pala(data) {
    $("#pala").html(data.level);
}
// Code below runs once when the page is ready.
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/ragnaros/sanral?fields=talents&jsonp=pala",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }
);
```